# Variables assignment better approach

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a shell script(beginner), which works fine but it includes a number of parameters.

I assign the value to them as show below.

```
url=$2
name=$3
ipadd=$5
netmask=$6
vlanid=$4
vlname=$7
```

Is there is any better approach, I can use ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is fine; it is direct, it is obvious what it does, and it is no longer than it needs to be.

Comment: You can put multiple assignments on one line if that is what bothers you.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/14203146#14203146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read` instead of multiple assignments:

```
f=$'\6'  # or any other control character 
IFS=$f read -d'' -r _ url name vlanid ipadd netmask vlname _ < <(printf "%s$f" "$@")
```

`_` will ignore `$1` and anything after `$8`.

Comment: If I have to assign one value to two variables

Comment: suppose $2 for vlanid and x ?

Comment: One line != better. In fact, this is worse, because it doesn't work if any of the positional parameters themselves contain whitespace. ("$@" is not a list of separate quoted words here; the whole thing is just one string fed to `read`.)

Comment: You're right. I have corrected it now to take care of whitespaces in parameters.

Comment: Your update assumes none of the values contains a newline. It might work for the intended values, but it still doesn't actually improve on the original.

Comment: ok updated further to handle newlines as well but yes it doesn't have the simplicity of individual assignments.

Comment: Just wanted to know from professional point of you is it fine ? I was reading few scripts on github didn't find this kind of pattern

Comment: Multiple assignments are fine but you must quote them in assignment.

Comment: This is of course broken, by design. This would be better: `i=2; for var in url name vlanid ipadd netmask vlname; do printf -v "$var" '%s' "${!i}"; i=$((i+1)); done`. But at this point, OP's method isn't that bad (clear and readable and shorter).

Comment: Yes agreed @gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 0):

The only way I would see really doing a better job would be to change to a --flag=value setup, if only to not make the order of arguments as important.

./myscript.sh --url=http://www.example.com --ip=10.42.56.23 --netmask=24

This would then require parsing each argument for the --flag part, then if it is found splitting the variable at the = and setting the value of your real internal value.  Worth it for something you are shipping out to users, but maybe not so much for something you are using for yourself.